# Chisel Bootcamp 2.5 exercise for converting to tilelink based for and tester. Elaboration fine but gives TLMonitor assertion error

Tags: chisel

I have gone through the documentations in chipyard and chisel tutorials. While trying out the chisel bootcamp chapter 2.5 exercise I get the following assertion error.

```
Assertion failed: 'A' channel Get carries invalid source ID (connected at DspBlock.scala:113:7)
at Monitor.scala:75 assert (source_ok, "'A' channel Get carries invalid source ID" + extra)
Assertion failed: 'A' channel Get contains invalid mask (connected at DspBlock.scala:113:7)
at Monitor.scala:78 assert (bundle.mask === mask, "'A' channel Get contains invalid mask" + extra)
```

Code snippet:

```scala
class TLFIRBlockTester(c: TLFIRBlock with TLStandaloneBlock) extends FIRBlockTester(c) with TLMasterModel {
  def memTL = c.ioMem.get
}

val lm = LazyModule(new TLFIRBlock(1, 8)(Parameters.empty) with TLStandaloneBlock)

chisel3.iotesters.Driver(() => lm.module) { _ => new TLFIRBlockTester(lm) }
```

The assertion errors indicate that source ID,mask are invalid on channel A. I have noticed that the below file has the relevant classes for TLMasterModel tat has the memWriteWord that inturn drives the Channel A inputs for source and mask.

https://github.com/ucb-bar/dsptools/blob/master/rocket/src/main/scala/tl/TestIP.scala

Could you please suggest on how i can resolve this issue.